# How to get an inner class in Java Reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, inner-classes

I have the following class:

```
package me.victor.test;

public class ContainerClass {

    public class InnerClass {
        // ...
    }
}
```

How can I get the `Class` type of the `InnerClass` using reflection?

Using: `Class.forName("me.victor.test.ContainerClass.InnerClass");` throws a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: Nested classes uses `$` as the separator between themselves and the enclosing class in their qualified name.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of the one posted. The other post was about static inner classes, this is about non-static inner classes.

Comment: @user1886323 The solution is the same. Duplicates are about answers, not questions.

Comment: @user1886323 Also, _inner_ classes are, by definition, non-static nested classes. It's redundant to qualify an inner class as non-static.

Comment: Nowhere in the accepted answer does it state that the answer is the same for non-static inner classes. In fact, there is even a comment on the question saying the nested classes and inner classes are different.

Comment: I think that's more about the title of this question then - I have suggested a change. Furthermore, the answers to the "duplicate" do not mention nested classes.

Comment: @user1886323 The answer is the same for all nested classes. Inner classes are nested classes. If you think the answers in the duplicate are poor, downvote them. If you think they are incomplete, provide an answer of your own.

Comment: @user1886323 Your edit suggestion is invalid since OP is asking about inner (non-static nested) class, not any nested class. But since solution is same for all nested classes closing this question as duplicate was correct decision. I edited accepted answer in duplicate question to state that it will work for both static and non-static nested classes.

Comment: Pshemo you're right. However, as the other answers make no mention of non-static "inner" classes and the question specifically asks about "static inner" or "nested" classes then it's absurd to call the questions duplicates. Programming is supposed to be a science, not a guessing game, and frankly anyone who assumes that static inner classes behave in the same way to non-static ones would be very much mistaken. For this reason there is no reason to say that the "duplicate" answers the question of how to load non-static inner classes.

Comment: Furthermore, downvoting the answer on the other question is a ridiculous suggestion because it answers the question. Which by the way, as you may have noticed I have pointed out :p is a different question!